# Automatic mailbox getting created in database which is excluded from provisioning

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, exchange-server-2013

I am trying to create an automatic mailbox from my application I am not passing any database parameter in enable-mailbox cmdlet but the mailboxes are getting created in a database which has been excluded from provisioning. The Mailbox Resources Management agent is enabled in my exchange server . I have tried doing the same in native where it works fine . Am i missing something?